# codeigniter var_dump size output not ok

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, var-dump

Someone can tell me why it output this :

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(2) "52"
[1]=>
string(10) "Tofu ferme"
[2]=>
string(1) "1"
[3]=>
string(17) "paquet(s)"
}
```

The 17 ??

Comment: The code that added the data to the array would be more helpful than the dump.

Comment: there is likely html content there like a wrapping span tag

Comment: What encoding do you use? And how that array is produced ?

Comment: The other possible reason is to have BOM in the beginning of that string.

Comment: I'm using smarty and url encode 
       {assign var="unite" value=$recette[$i]->nom_unite|default:'empty'|urlencode} 


After receive the data, i'm using url decode

Comment: Someone can help me ? Because it's always false when I do a query " where column like $var"  because the size of this last argument.. even if the string is the same.. I'm searching a lot of functions since five hours, and nothing founds..
There isn't a magical function ? :D

Comment: please try inspecting element (in browser) if browser is not rendering tags or something simillar. Open up google chrome and right click on "paquet(s)" and hit "Inspect Element". This is the best way to debug it.

Comment: Ho yeah I found it :   string(16) "tasse&#40;s&#41;" holy ..This represents the parentheses ( and ) ..
So i don't know how to recup the real "tasse(s)", size : 8 ..

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to padding (either from left or right of string).  Try **VIEWING SOURCE** of your `var_dump()` and not the html generated.  The HTML source might show you padding.

You could clean up the padding by running a simple **[trim()](https://www.php.net/trim)** function on the variable.

*Otherwise I am just guessing since you show very little in your question. You could offer more input on what this variable is, and where you get this questionable french string length.*